# What is the difference between template call?

Tags: c++, templates

What is the difference between A, B and C calls?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T> T max(T a, T b) {
    return (a >= b) ? a : b;
}

int main() {
    float a = 4.0;
    float b = 6.0f;
    cout << max(a, b) << endl; //A
    cout << max<double>(a, b) << endl; //B
    cout << max<double>(4.0, 6.0f) << endl; //C
}
```

Comment: Same things, except return value and some implicit conversion (float -> double)

Comment: This is how you find out what function is generated:
To the function add this line:
`std::cout << (__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First invocation of `max` is actually `max<float>`, second and third is the same `max<double>`

But in second invocation both `a` and `b` get promoted to double, where in third the example only `6.0f` is promoted to double.

Answer (score -1):

A calls `std::max<float>`, since a and b are float arguments. In B and C, you force it to call `std::max<double>`, thus both arguments are converted to double.